# Using dopri5 for ODE Integration and Stochastic Simulations

Tags: python, scipy

I'm still very much a beginner in python, but had some questions about running simulations (I apologize if this is the wrong area to post my question in which case, if someone would kindly show me where it would be better suited, I will gladly move it). My goal is to simulate the following system of differential equations:

[image]

Because the dynamical system was experiencing stiffness, the odeint method of integration I learned kept having problems, so I tried to integrate it another way, namely using the dopri5 method I have heard about. It seems to work but I've noticed some odd behavior in the plots. The code I was using is as follows:

```
import scipy as sp
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

#Constants
c13 = 6.2
c14 = 1.0
c21 = 7.3
c32 = 2.4
c34 = 12.7
c42 = 5.7
c43 = 5.0

e12 = 1.5
e23 = 2.5
e24 = 2.0
e31 = 3.0
e41 = 4.8

#Time
t_end = 300.
t_start = 0.
t_step = 1.
t_interval = sp.arange(t_start, t_end, t_step)

#Initial Condition
ic = [0.6,0.3,0.2,0.5]

#Noise
sigma1 = 0.1
sigma2 = 0.1
sigma3 = 0.1
sigma4 = 0.1

def model(t,ic):
    Eqs= np.zeros((4))
    Eqs[0] = ic[0]+(ic[0]*(1-ic[0]*ic[0]-ic[1]*ic[1]-ic[2]*ic[2]-ic[3]*ic[3])-c21*((ic[1]*ic[1])*ic[0])+e31*((ic[2]*ic[2])*ic[0])+e41*((ic[3]*ic[3])*ic[0]))
    Eqs[1] = ic[1]+(ic[1]*(1-ic[0]*ic[0]-ic[1]*ic[1]-ic[2]*ic[2]-ic[3]*ic[3])+e12*((ic[0]*ic[0])*ic[1])-c32*((ic[2]*ic[2])*ic[1])-c42*((ic[3]*ic[3])*ic[1]))
    Eqs[2] = ic[2]+(ic[2]*(1-ic[0]*ic[0]-ic[1]*ic[1]-ic[2]*ic[2]-ic[3]*ic[3])-c13*((ic[0]*ic[0])*ic[2])+e23*((ic[1]*ic[1])*ic[2])-c43*((ic[3]*ic[3])*ic[2]))
    Eqs[3] = ic[3]+(ic[3]*(1-ic[0]*ic[0]-ic[1]*ic[1]-ic[2]*ic[2]-ic[3]*ic[3])-c14*((ic[0]*ic[0])*ic[3])+e24*((ic[1]*ic[1])*ic[3])-c34*((ic[2]*ic[2])*ic[3]))
    return Eqs

ode =  spi.ode(model)
ode.set_integrator('dopri5',method='bdf')
ode.set_initial_value(ic,t_start)
ts = []
ys = []

while ode.successful() and ode.t < t_end:
    ode.integrate(ode.t + t_step)
    ts.append(ode.t)
    ys.append(ode.y)

t = np.vstack(ts)
x1,x2,x3,x4 = np.vstack(ys).T

plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, x1, 'b')
plt.xlim([0,t_end])

plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, x2, 'r')
plt.xlim([0,t_end])

plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, x3, 'g')
plt.xlim([0,t_end])

plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
plt.plot(t, x4, 'purple')
plt.xlim([0,t_end])
plt.xlabel('Time')

plt.show()
```

However, the plot looks like this:

[image]

What I don't understand is why the plots reach a maximum of about 1.4. I did some analytical work and cross-referenced it with another paper that used these equations, and the maximum value it should reach is 1. Is it something in the dopri5 code that makes it go above 1? I also don't understand why there's a bit of spike appearing early on in each of the blue peaks (x1).

My other question is that I would like to do some stochastic simulation with these equations. So for this part, the equations I would like to work with are of the form:

dx_i = ()dt + sigma_i * x_i * dW_t

where dW_t is white noise. However, when I tried to modify the above equation and do this for example:

```
Eqs[0] = ic[0]+(ic[0]*(1-ic[0]*ic[0]-ic[1]*ic[1]-ic[2]*ic[2]-ic[3]*ic[3])-c21*((ic[1]*ic[1])*ic[0])+e31*((ic[2]*ic[2])*ic[0])+e41*((ic[3]*ic[3])*ic[0]))+sigma1*ic[0]*np.random.normal(0,1)
```

the code fails to run properly. It seems that what I wrote is not the proper method for making these equations stochastic. What is the best way to put stochastic perturbations into these equations? I've recently heard of something called PyS3DE but I know nothing about it.

Comment: FYI: `dopri5` is for *nonstiff* systems.  The `set_integrator` method accepts the argument `method='bdf'` without complaining, but that argument is ignored when `dopri5` is used.  (Yeah, I know, that's really annoying.)  Also, `scipy.integrate.odeint` is a wrapper of the Fortran code `LSODA`, which automatically detects stiffness and switches to a stiff solver when appropriate, so if you really had problems with stiffness, your switch from `odeint` to the `dopri5` solver of the `ode` class doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: *"My other question..."*  It is best to ask just one question at a time.

Comment: Why do you have `Eqs[0] = ic[0] + ...`?  The isolated term `ic[0]` is not in the equations given above. (Likewise for the other equations in `model`.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The "Eqs[0] = ic[0] + ..." term is because I'm an idiot who can't translate my code from a different scheme I used before. Thank you for finding that! The problem when I was using odeint was that the variables x1, x2, etc were taking negative values: (http://oi57.tinypic.com/352jhq8.jpg). I thought dopri5 was for stiff systems, so that's my mistake, but dopri5 certainly seems to give more accurate results in this case. It was a former TA of mine who suggested my equations were very stuff, so I'm trying to find the best way to integrate them properly

Comment: You should get a good solution with `dopri5`, but it will likely do a lot more work (and so take a longer time) than a stiff solver.  You could also try `'vode'`, which *does* accept and actually use `method='bdf'`. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html for more options.